# How do I upsert data into SharePoint list from Synapse table using logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sharepoint-list, azure-synapse-analytics

This is my first Logic App design. The app succeeds on the first execution to get rows from synapse and insert them to empty SharePoint list. When I run it second time without new rows from the source so it finishes without appending no new records to SharePoint list, it fails when appending array values from SharePoint list. I can use help to see where things go wrong.

This is where it failed
[image]

Here is the logic I used array to pick unique identifier from SharePoint list and check if it exists at source.
[image]

Thanks
Sam